# SQL query to find out the number of tickets

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access.

Table 1: users

```
ID (auto int)
Name
```

Table 2: tickets

```
ID (auto int)
userName (int) (refers to ID in users table)
```

How can I list the user names and the number of tickets submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the results that you want. You will want to use an aggregate function `COUNT()` and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT u.name, count(t.username) TicketsSubmitted
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN tickets t
    ON u.id = t.username
GROUP BY u.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the tickets per user in a subquery, then list all the info per user.

```
SELECT u.Name AS UserName, t.ticketCount AS TicketsSubmitted
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(ID), userName AS ticketCount FROM tickets GROUP BY userName ) AS t
ON u.ID = t.userName
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A make table query should allow you to query those two tables and create a third with the data you want.

The following link from the Microsoft Office website should give you the information you need.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-make-table-query-HA010108505.aspx

The two answers above give solid advice for the query to get the data you want.